# Running PHP Process in the background from a Browser on Windows

Tags: php

I'm a little sorry to ask this as I know that it has been asked many times before on here but all of the answers I have found do not work in my situation. Either I am doing something fundamentally wrong or I am trying to do something which is just not possible.

I need to be able to fork a background process from a PHP file accessed via a web browser (served up by an Apache web server running on Windows). I need the foreground process to finish, and therefore the browser to stop waiting for the server whilst the forked process continues in the background. I am using PHP 5.3.

I have tried numerous suggested solutions all with varying degree of fail:

```
shell_exec('D:\php5.3\php.exe sleep.php > out 2>out2' );
```

Whether ran through command line, or through browser, the foreground process did not complete until the background one did. Adding a "&" in at the end didn't seem to make any difference

```
pclose(popen("start D:\php5.3\php.exe sleep.php","r"));
```

This one worked fine through command line, but when accessed via browser, it waited for both foreground and background processes to finish.

```
exec("nohup D:/php5.3/php.exe -f sleep.php > out 2>out2");
```

This didn't seem to work at all

```
$commandString = "start /b D:/php5.3/php.exe d:\\webroot\\other\\tests\\sleep.php"; 
pclose(popen($commandString, 'r'));
```

Worked in command line, waited in browser

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("D:/php5.3/php-win.exe -f d:\\webroot\\other\\tests\\sleep.php", 0, false);
```

didn't work at all - hung when trying to fork the new process.

Can anyone help? Am I missing something really obvious?!

I know I can queue the tasks up in a database and run in batch, but I need this to operate in as close to real time as possible so do not want to introduce more delays by queueing things up that I can then only run max once a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You might try pcntl_fork functions.  This can fork a child process (serving the web page) while continuing to do the rest of the work in the work in the background.  It is however something that needs to be used with caution.  Just read through the php.net documentation to get a feel for some of the complexities of using this approach.

Comment: I don't think that is available in Windows? And from what I have read it's pretty dodgy in an Apache/webserver environment?

Comment: I have used it in the past, but mainly for spawning a bunch of child class to perform load testing.  I am strictly in Linux environment, so don't know about it's applicability to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

even this post is outdated but may it be useful for others,
this worked for me, it took hours to find the solution!

```
function execInBack($phpscript, $args = array(), $logfile = '', $stdoutfile = '') {
if (count($args) == 0) {
    $args[] = md5(mt_rand());
}

$arg = '';

foreach ($args as $a) {
    $arg .= "\"$a\" ";
}

$cmd = "start /b c:\php\php5.3.10\php.exe ./$phpscript $arg";
$p = array();

$desc = array();
if ($logfile && $stdoutfile) {
    $desc = array(
        1 => array("file", $stdoutfile, "w"),
        2 => array("file", $logfile, "a")
    );
}

proc_close(proc_open($cmd, $desc, $p, getcwd()));
```

}